# WPF CellEditingTemplate and duplicated events

Tags: wpf, events, binding, datagridtemplatecolumn, celleditingtemplate

I've a WPF DataGrid with a DataGridTemplateColumn like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            TextChanged="ctl_TextChanged" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I noticed that every time I go into a cell edit, a new textbox control is generated and, consequently, if I start typing a character, the TextChanged event is invoked several times...once for each instance of the control that was generated!

Sample project to reproduce the issue: [TestEditingTemplate_4.5.2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnw0d7y82wfgpcz/TestEditingTemplate_4.5.2.zip?dl=0)

I used the TextChanged event only for example, but the issue may also occur with other events (eg. events defined within a UserControl)

Is there is a way to avoid this behavior?
I wish to destroy the "edit" control on CellEditEnding, so that it does not interfere with the new control generated when I return to cell edit; how can I do?

Comment: The TextChanged should only be invoked once for each key press. Your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: I've created a simple application with a DataGrid and a DataGridTemplateColumn...the problem is reproducible; if edit same cell 2 times, then at each key press the event is invoked 2 times...and so on (.NET 4.0)

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I am not on .NET 4.0 though but the oldest officially supported version is 4.5.2 so you should probably update.

Comment: I tried with 4.5.2, but no change...here there is the sample project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjtirGjxfFwZhVw-y-jfge9doVuk